# Social login api from keycloak

Tags: oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, keycloak, openid-connect, keycloak-rest-api

[image]

I want to use keycloak social login from react js client side and backend side node js. I can't find any way of generating the red marked link from keycloak.

http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/softspace/broker/github/login?client_id=account&tab_id=qXW9kuQnfu0&session_code=WGGXv87kK9R9m0KOoq5RPAwmqR131DaZwyzOvT_SWd8

I don't know how they generating the **tab_id** and **session_code**.

I have an client react app which needs to social sign on [image]

When I will click on such github button,I want to find the way of going to directly[image]

Answer (score 3):

One approach is to set the default provider of the Realm in question. For that go to the Keycloak Admin Console and:

- Select your `Realm`;
- Select `Authentication`;
- From the `tab Flows`:

  - Select `Browser`;
  - In `Identity Provider Redirector` (Git) click on `Actions` (on the right);
  - click on `Config`.
  - to the `Default Identity Provider` set to the name of the IDP the one that you have configured.

When you access the URL `<KEYCLOAK>/auth/realms/<YOUR_REALM>/account` you will get redirected to the GitHub page. Now bear in mind that this set up will be applied to the entire Realm.

The other option is to use "kc_idp_hint":

> When this switch is on, this provider will not be shown as a login
> option on the login page. Clients can still request to use this
> provider by using the 'kc_idp_hint' parameter in the URL they use to
> request a login.

If you try to login with the URL:

```
<KEYCLOAK_HOST>/auth/realms/<YOUR_REALM_NAME>/protocol/openid-connect/auth?client_id=<YOUR_CLIENT_ID>&redirect_uri=<THE_REDIRECT_URI>&response_type=code&scope=openid&kc_idp_hint=<the_name_that_you_give_to_the_idp>
```

you should be redirect to the GitHub login page.