# How to use social signin for custom react page with keycloak

Tags: node.js, reactjs, keycloak, keycloak-rest-api, keycloak-connect

I want to implement something like login with google but with keycloak and also I want to use custom react page. For instance, there is a google icon button and after clicking on that button user should be redirected to social login.

Also is there any way I can get jwt token of user that uses social signin to login to the application. There is an api for login with username and password but I can not find anything related to social login token.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please, check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65183383

In order to achieve the social login with a custom page, the second option (kc_idp_hint) is what you need.

Comment: It is not an answer, it should be moved into comments and question be flagged as duplicate

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm new here and don't have reputation yet to write comments on other's publications.